Analytic continuation of integral
I'm looking to analytically continue this function defined by an integral to the complex plane.
$$I(s)=2\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \int_{J=(0,n^{-s/2})} e^{\frac{\log^2({n^{s/2}})}{\log t}}~dt$$
By leveraging the involutive symmetry of the integrand I was able to decompose $I(s)$ into a sum of triangular components and a sum of Bessel components.
$$ I(s)=\zeta(s)+s\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \log n~K_1(s\log n) $$
So we can write this as $$ I(s)=\zeta(s)+sf(s)$$
where $$f(s)=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \log n~K_1(s\log n)$$
It looks like $f(s)$ (Bessel function) and $\zeta(s)$ (Riemann zeta function) both have poles of order $1$ at $s=1.$ $\zeta(s)$ has a well-known analytic continuation. Both functions are real analytic for real $s>1$.

How might one find the maximal analytic continuation of $I(s)$?

